# Swing if else statement

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have an annoying message box that pops up when I dont want it.
the problem occurs after a user logs on and the hidden button is visible, but when it is clicked it show the "correct" message again? Ive also tried putting it on top of the first statement and bottom.
EDIT:The annoying message is the message that comes up after a successful login, and no I dont need to spell check,

```
class MyWindowListener extends WindowAdapter {

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Closing window!");
        System.exit(0);

    }
}
class LoginForm extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private final String username = "user";
    private final String password = "pass";
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel jPanel;
    JLabel userLabel;
    final JTextField userText;
    JLabel passLabel;
    final JPasswordField passText;
    JButton loginBtn;
    JButton shopBtn;
    JLabel welcome;

    {

        frame = new JFrame();
        jPanel = new JPanel();
        userLabel = new JLabel("Login : ");
        userText = new JTextField(10); 
        passLabel = new JLabel("Password : ");
        passText = new JPasswordField(10);
        loginBtn = new JButton("Login");
        shopBtn = new JButton("Go to Shop");
        welcome = new JLabel("Welcome to ECSE501 Computers");
        setTitle("Login Page");
        loginBtn.addActionListener(this);
        shopBtn.addActionListener(this);


        Container c1 = new Container();
        c1.setLayout(new GridLayout (3,2));
        c1.add(userLabel);
        c1.add(userText);
        c1.add(passLabel);
        c1.add(passText);
        c1.add(loginBtn);

        Container c2 = new Container();
        c2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(c2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        c2.add(welcome);
        c2.add(shopBtn);
        welcome.setVisible(false);
        shopBtn.setVisible(false);

        add(jPanel);
        jPanel.add(c1);
        jPanel.add(c2);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String userInput = userText.getText();
        char[] pass = passText.getPassword();
        String p = new String(pass);



        if (userInput.equals(username) && p.equals(password)) {
            jPanel.setVisible(true);
            welcome.setVisible(true);
            jPanel.setBackground(Color.green);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct");
            shopBtn.setVisible(true);
            JButton hiddenBtn = (JButton) e.getSource();
        if ( hiddenBtn == shopBtn)  
         {
            SelectionForm selection = new SelectionForm();
            selection.select();
        }
        }
        else {   
            jPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Login Details");

        }


    }
}
public class LoginTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        // register an event handler for frame events
        LoginForm frame = new LoginForm();
        frame.addWindowListener(new MyWindowListener());
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //frame.pack();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide the complete program it seem you calling this fuction in a loop ! (as the main part)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) *`"Corerect"`*  Incorrect.  Use a spell checker.  3) What is the exact text of the *"annoying message"*?

Comment: `"Corerect"`? I'd be annoyed if that popped up on me. Sorry, couldn't resist the irony.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put this all in your `actionPerformed` method. That is called whenever any action is performed, a button is clicked, a text field is edited, etc...

If you don't want this to run when you click the button, check for the source of the event, using `getSource()`, and if the source is the button, then don't run the code. Your method would look like this:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String userInput = userText.getText();
        char[] pass = passText.getPassword();
        String p = new String(pass);

        if(e.getSource().equals(loginBtn)) {

            if (userInput.equals(username) && p.equals(password)) {

                jPanel.setVisible(true);
                welcome.setVisible(true);
                jPanel.setBackground(Color.green);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct");
                shopBtn.setVisible(true);
                JButton hiddenBtn = (JButton) e.getSource();
            }

            else {
                jPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Login Details");
            }
        }

        else if (e.getSource().equals(shopBtn)) {

            SelectionForm selection = new SelectionForm();
            selection.select();

        }
}
```

Comment: every time the "Go to Shop"/shopBtn button is clicked is the message shows again.

Comment: Maybe it's because I used "!=" instead of !equals(). I'll change that. If it still doesn't work after this change, replace JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Corerect"); with JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getSource()); in order to see what called it.

Comment: I didnt really explain it properly because I was very tired. I want the message to open but onlu once, after the user has a successful login. Then a hidden button will show and when that it is clicked it opens a new frame and displays the "correct" message again which I dont want.

Comment: Oh, I see. So you want the form to show up if the shopBtn is clicked, and you want the dialog to show up if the right username and password are entered? Okay. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I should have put an else if right? well its working, thank you.

Comment: Basically what I did is that I checked the source of the event. If it was the shopBtn, I opened up the selection form. If it was the loginBtn, then I checked the password and showed the dialog. I think that this is what you were trying to do, but your spacing took away from the readability of your code, and you didn't put the if statements in the right places.